# Python strip chart line segment keeps appearing

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I've modified the [strip chart example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/strip_chart_demo.html) to make an animated moving line.  However every time I move the strip chart over, the first 2 line segments get replotted.  As shown here on my screen shot:

[image: example1]

However if I hit the "save" button on the Figure and save it the extra line segment isn't there.  (Note, these are 2 different test runs with different random data, but on my screen the two extra segments are always present when the animation is running)
[image: example]

It also doesn't plot immediately in the animation.  The first 2 segments will plot and then it will show up on the plot.  These values aren't in the data lists for tdata or ydata.  Here's the sample code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation


class Scope:
    def __init__(self, ax, maxt=5, dt=1):
        self.ax = ax
        self.dt = dt
        self.maxt = maxt
        self.tdata = []

        self.tdata.append(0)
        self.ydata = []
        self.ydata.append(20)
        self.line = Line2D(self.tdata, self.ydata)
        self.ax.add_line(self.line)
        self.ax.set_ylim(21, 24)
        self.ax.set_xlim(0, self.maxt)

    def update(self, y):
        lastt = self.tdata[-1]
        if lastt > self.tdata[0] + self.maxt: # reset the arrays
            self.tdata = [self.tdata[-1]]
            self.ydata = [self.ydata[-1]]
            self.ax.set_xlim(self.tdata[0], self.tdata[0] + self.maxt)
            self.ax.figure.canvas.draw()

        t = self.tdata[-1] + self.dt
        self.tdata.append(t)
        self.ydata.append(y)
        self.line.set_data(self.tdata, self.ydata)
        return self.line,


def fetchPrice():
    yield np.random.rand(1) + 23


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
scope = Scope(ax)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, scope.update, fetchPrice, interval=1000,
                              blit=True)

plt.show()
```

Let me know if you have any ideas about what is going on and how to fix it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's caused by wrong indentation. Dedent the line in `update` (See `<----` marked line in the following code):

```
def update(self, y):
    lastt = self.tdata[-1]
    if lastt > self.tdata[0] + self.maxt: # reset the arrays
        self.tdata = [self.tdata[-1]]
        self.ydata = [self.ydata[-1]]
        self.ax.set_xlim(self.tdata[0], self.tdata[0] + self.maxt)
    self.ax.figure.canvas.draw()       # <---- 

    t = self.tdata[-1] + self.dt
    self.tdata.append(t)
    self.ydata.append(y)
    self.line.set_data(self.tdata, self.ydata)
    return self.line,
```

Comment: @user6972, According to [`FuncAnimation` documentation](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/api/animation_api.html#matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation): If `blit=True`, `func` and `init_func` should return an iterable of drawables to clear. Your code does not provided `init_func`, it seems like matplotlib reuse first return value of the `update` method to clear the frame.

Comment: @user6972, ALTERNATIVE 1: Specifying `blit=False` also solved the problem for me.

Comment: @user6972, ALTERNATIVE 2: Passing additional `init_func=lambda: (scope.line,)` to the `FuncAnimation` also solved the problem.